# Should you teach different cues to help a dog know to go wider during an away and go-by inside flank?

Tags: dogs, training, herding

Should you teach different cues to help a dog know to go wider during an away and go-by inside flank? Obviously we know we need different cues for the away and go-by flanks and those cues are also used for the inside flank. But what about a cue to indicate a wider go-by vs. away inside flank?

I know that some of the top trainers out there have different cues for each and I'm wondering why the difference is needed and if it has to do with just the inside flank or if you should have different cues for going wider on a normal flank as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see a need to differentiate the behavior - why teach different signals?
Some of the leading trainers in the field will do seminars - they might be able to give an answer to the why and at the same time start to give you a solution to the 'how' for the teaching of the dog.